# Mule Runtime version mistmatch

Tags: mule, mule-studio

- Downloaded Anypoint Studio 3.6. Connected to the Exchanged and open
  the "hello world" example in the studio. I ran the flow and
  everything worked.
- Then installed the latest community edition runtime (3.5) from
  http://studio.mulesoft.org/r3/studio-runtimes and restarted Anypoint
  Studio
- Edited the "hello world" application's run configuration to use the
  community edition runtime.
- Executed the updated run configuration and received warning "There is
  a Mule runtime version mismatch between the projects configuration
  and the launch configuration".
- I select to "Continue with launch" and receive a Java stack dump:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Application name not specified.
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer$ApplicationDeployerArguments.parse(ApplicationDeployer.java:60)
```

1. It looks like the HelloWorld.xml file (the definition of the Mule Flow) needs to be changed.

   - What do I need to change to make this thing run?
   - What constitutes a valid Mule Flow XML? I can't find any documentation or books that specify how to read or edit a Mule Flow XML. Am I missing something? I distrust visual programming and I would  like a guide to writing valid Mule Flows in XML. Does such a thing exist?
2. It is not seamless to switch between EE and CE runtimes. In fact, I cannot find much documentation on anything other than Anypoint Studio. All the examples of how to use the Mule runtime appear to have been removed from the github repository. Is this an case of "open source" washing, where a company claims  their product is open source, but the open source code is something you would never try to use?

Comment: Did you change the runtime version in the `mule-project.xml` config file as well?

Comment: Answering `2.`: Welcome to Mule's huge lack of documentation world. I've used Mule CE 3.4 for a while. Although it was really hard to find examples and documentation, CE proven to be actually useful and works fine; the difference form EE is that you get less really useful resources (such as [DataMapper](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/DataMapper+Concepts)) and no support at all (don't even try).

Comment: Trying to answer `1.`: Have you tried installing Mule Server 3.5? AFAIK Anypoint Studio can handle different Server versions to support different Runtimes. Try going Help > Install New Software, select [Anypoint Studio Update Site](http://studio.mulesoft.org/r3/updates) and select the matching Mule Server version to your project (3.5). Just a suggestion, not sure this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anypoint Studio 5.0.x or 5.1.x (required to use ESB 3.6) then you need to install the runtimes from the preinstalled update site (http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/studio-runtimes/). Using the r3 update site may be causing issues.

To change the XML flow files version you need to edit the version attribute in the  element. Example . It should be equal or less than the runtime version, and be of an existing version.

You need to set the project name and expected runtime at mule-project.xml as David Dossot said. Note that this is different to the actual runtime at execution time, at least in Studio 5.x.x.

Read the docs at https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Home for information on flow elements and configuration. The tutorials may be a good place to start.

You can use the visual editor to start, and switch between the graphical edit (message flow) and XML edit (Configuration XML) views easily during development, to get your taste of the configurations.

The Mule ESB open source project is still at https://github.com/mulesoft/mule.